# Firebase Hosting Usage Stats - what does "Storage" stand for?

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

I am having a hard time getting my head around the "Storage" number under Firebase Hosting > Usage tab.

According to its corresponding tooltip, the Storage number shows the bytes stored. My understanding is that this is the size of my website. But then I am getting ~280 MB for this Storage number while my website is only 712 KB (ie. The size of the public root directory of my website).

Is the Storage number supposed to be the size of my website? If no, how should I interpret it?

Comment: It would be nice to see some feedback as to why my question got downvoted. Downvoting without leaving a comment is really pointless.

Comment: Let me know if my ask is not clear. I would try to explain further. Thx

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The storage counter measures all space used by your hosting files on Google's servers.

This includes the current version of the deployed site and **any previously deployed versions** that you haven't deleted. The latter can easily add up, since (due to the convenience of `firebase deploy`) you end up deploying a lot of versions.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It's exactly what I need to know. I wasn't aware of the fact all previously deployed versions are kept. That's the piece of information that I was missing.

Comment: Frank, I have a follow-up question for you regarding this subject. I deleted all previously deployed version and now the Storage size has reduced to ~80 MB from ~280 MB, which is amazing (thanks to you). But my original concern holds still. Why is the Storage size (80 MB) noticeably larger than the size of the public root directory (712 KB) of my Firebase project? Thank you once again.

Comment: That seems unexpected. Can you follow up via Firebase support with the specifics of your project so we can take a look?

Comment: @MichaelBleigh - Will do. Thank you.